# Oven Functionality causing the main circuit to trip

Tags: oven

I've been using my oven normally for bakeries , recently I've facing an problem with it whenever I turned it on it trips the main circuit of the apartment! This happended after switching on the grill mode, even just switching on the light of the oven causes the same.
Despite the oven not functioning I can normally use the stove without any issues!
Can you highlight what might be the possible reason for this?
Thank you!

Comment: What make and model is said oven?  Also, I take it your main is a RCD? (I-delta-n on the front)

Comment: gram ek 60 02 taf alu, this is the model and make

Comment: Where are you in the world? Do you have a RCD , an element starting to fail could be leaking to ground and causing the rcd to trip so more information would be needed to be sure but that’s where I would be looking.